# Jest: Unexpected value 'NgxsRootModule' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation

Tags: jestjs, ngxs, angular13

I'm getting the following error when running a test in Jest, using Angular 13:

```
 Unexpected value 'NgxsRootModule' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation.

      41 |
      42 |   beforeEach(() => {
    > 43 |     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
```

which appears to be related to this `beforeEach` block that I have:

```
beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
          FormComponentsModule,
          MatButtonModule,
          NoopAnimationsModule,
          ReactiveFormsModule,
          RouterTestingModule,
          MatSnackBarModule,
          MatIconModule,
          MatCardModule,
          NgxsModule.forRoot([])
        ],
        declarations: [MyComponent],
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
        teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false }
      }).compileComponents();
    })
  );
```

But if I remove the `forRoot([])` part it then just compains about `NgxsModule` in the same way.

This also works fine with Angular 11 & 12. It's only since upgrading to Angular 13 (which required upgrades of Jest to the latest version) that this problem has appeared.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why it now doesn't like the use `NgxsRootModule`?

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Have you found a solution? I am on Angular 14 and "jest-preset-angular": "~12.2.0",

Answer (score 9):

First, you should update the `jest-preset-angular` plugin to the latest version.

After that in your ‘jest.config.js’ file, you need to have the line:
`globalSetup: 'jest-preset-angular/global-setup'`

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts'],
  globalSetup: 'jest-preset-angular/global-setup'
};
```

Read more: https://thymikee.github.io/jest-preset-angular/docs/guides/angular-13+/

Comment: Simply adding: 
globalSetup 'jest-preset-angular/global-setup' to jest.config.js 
worked, thank you!!

Comment: It looks like the reason this works is because it runs a preprocessor that was removed in jest-preset-angular because ng14 doesn't need it. But since we have Ng12 libraries in the module being tested, it is still needed.